# What are the best ways to learn Salesforce?

Tags: java, developer

What would be the transition time for a PHP/Java developer to salesforce developer?

What is the best way of learning salesforce development?

Do I need to have the CRM knowledge of salesforce to become a SFDC Developer?

There are number of exams available in the market, will doing these exam lead me to the path of a SFDC developer?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Help & Training via a partner portal, that is the best way of starting salesforce path,

Trailhead gives you a good starting point about all the basics and this is a good place to start your salesforce learning.

I would not recommend doing certification exams without having some hands-on experience, these exams are to prove your ability to use/admin/dev on the CRM.

So in general start with Trailhead